# WPDB Placeholders and second argument for prepared statements

Tags: wpdb, sql

How can I set placeholder and second argument for that kind of sql prepare

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT ID 
     FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
     WHERE post_type = 'attachment' AND ID IN ('".implode("','",$slideshow_imgs)."') 
     ORDER BY menu_order ASC"
);
```

ANSWER??

I do it that way and there is no debug error:

```
$str = 'attachment';

$ids_img = implode("','",$slideshow_imgs);

 $images = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
WHERE post_type = %s AND ID IN (%d) ORDER BY menu_order ASC",$str,$ids_img));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `%s` for string and `%d` for digit replacements. Do not forget to use the proper `esc_*()` functions (use full text search for `esc_` in the [function reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference)).

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->show_errors = true;
$wpdb->suppress_errors = false;
! defined( 'DIEONDBERROR' ) and define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT ID 
FROM {$wpdb->posts} 
    WHERE post_type = 'attachment' 
    AND ID IN (%s) 
    ORDER BY menu_order 
    ASC
SQL;

# Make sure to `esc_*()` the arguments properly!
$statement = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, implode( "','", $slideshow_imgs ) );
# Example: Query … there are other methods as well:
$wpdb->query( $statement );
# DUMP the result and any possible errors
var_dump( $wpdb->last_query, $wpdb->last_error );
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but how can I use it in $wpdb->prepare() ... I must use this as it's required by reviewer.

Comment: @Michael I explained and showed you in the answer: There are placeholders. Please read the answer in detail – and do NOT forget to sanitize any arguments/input#.

Comment: ok so it doesn't work then. Incorrect wpdb::prepare -- Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder

Comment: Then you did either do not use my or @birgire example (but your own without argument), or you have something else like a `null` inside `$slideshow_imgs`…

Comment: $slideshow_img - is an array with image, there is no null index.

Comment: Not that this would answer both the questions that I have asked you. Now I updated the answer and you will get some debug output. File an edit to your question with that `var_dump()` output, then ping me again. Also do **not** ignore @birgire answer to this question. There are some valuable points in there that you should take into account.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL) in /var/www/xxxx/WORDPRESS/xxx/xxx/wp-content/themes/xxx/views/headers/header-standard.php on line 103

Comment: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder

Comment: I add som answer and now I haven't got any notice in debug mode.

Comment: Please, stay professional: No uppercase only "shouting" here. Aside from that: You posted some code, but not any description what is happening and what your output is, etc. Sorry but at this point I am out.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, instead of writing SQL queries by hand, is to use e.g.:

```
$post_ids = get_posts( 
    [
        'fields'    => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'attachments',
        'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
        'order'     => 'ASC',
        'post__in'  => wp_parse_id_list( $input_ids )
    ]
);
```

where the handy [wp_parse_id_list()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_parse_id_list/) core function is used to:

> Clean up an array, comma- or space-separated list of IDs.

This generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 1=1 
    AND wp_posts.ID IN (1,2,3) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachments' 
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC 
LIMIT 0, 5
```

if `$input_ids = [1,2,3]`.

But actually [this is how](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/dc5815146e1a42523445267317a7d8c4ecc21dd4/wp-includes/query.php#L2761-2763) the `post__in` input is sanitized in `WP_Query`:

```
$post__in = implode(',', array_map( 'absint', $q['post__in'] ));
$where .= " AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ($post__in)";
```

ps: I now remember posting a ticket [#34525](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/34525) suggesting using `wp_parse_id_list()` within `WP_Query` ;-)